# Escape the Cap via Downvotes?

Tags: discussion

Just curious,

If I downvote enough, let say so I have -10 points. Could I then get an upvote for 10 points, and later reverse those downvotes, to end with 210 net reputation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe not, I believe the -1's from downvotes you cast counts against the daily cap. So if you cast 10 downvotes, I believe your actual cap for the day is now 190.

Comment: Down votes cast after the rep cap actually remove 1 from your cap and 1 from your rep, so he'd actually lose *at least* 10 rep, and 20 if he left it like that.

Answer (score 1):

While the behavior in this case is well explained by Timothy, keep in mind that even if you do manage to game the system in a manner similar to this, a reputation recalc will result in a corrected tally.  These happen once or twice a year for everyone, and whenever a moderator believes there might be a reason to recalculate a specific user's reputation.